# Configuring apache benchmark to use different query parameters

Tags: performance, apache, webserver, benchmarking

I am stress/perf testing my http service using apache benchmark [ab].

I wanted to use different query parameters in the http call configuring say from a file. I found [this](http://chrismiles.info/dev/testing/ab/) patch which allows you to do that. I had following questions:

1] I downloaded the ab.c file but couldnt figure out where to put it. Currently my ab binary is in /usr/bin . If I put the ab.c in there and gcc ab.c I get bunch of errors, because it cannot find the headers etc. My /usr/lib/httpd/modules just has bunch of .so files. So basically any help in how to get the patch working is appreciated.

2] The licensing is not clear for the patch, It says: © Copyright Chris Miles 2007. All rights reserved. Can someone comment if I can use it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build `httpd` from [source][1].
`ab.c` is in the `support` sub directory. You will have to replace it before building. Also, note that you'll probably have to get source for version 2.2.4 (as the [link][5] you shared suggests).

I do not know your comfort level with compiling programs, but these links may be of help:

- [Compiling Software From Source Code][3]
- [Compiling a simple C program][4]

Considering what you're looking to achieve by doing this, see also: [Question 2602841][2].

1: httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22
  2: [Changing POST data used by Apache Bench per iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602841/changing-post-data-used-by-apache-bench-per-iteration)
  3: everydaylht.com/howtos/system-administration/compiling-software-from-source-code/
  4: luv.asn.au/overheads/compile.html
  5: chrismiles.info/dev/testing/ab/